# Using ArcMap Group Layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, layer-file, group-layer

I am working with multiple grouped layer files that when in the layer file they do not have any of the normal properties. For example, when I click on the properties for an individual layer within the group I only see the "General Tab" but when I drag the layer out of the group I am able to see all of the normal tabs (general, source, selection, etc...).

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please *edit* your question and add more details about your ArcMap version and what type of individual layers are in the group. Thanks!

Comment: My answer does not quite marry with your symptoms.  Can you please include a picture of your Table of Contents showing the group layer and its layers before and after you have dragged one of its layers out, please?  Are you actually using layer files (`*.lyr`) in this workflow?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't right-clicking on the group layer itself and going to properties. If that is what you are doing, you will only see "General", "Group", and "Display" tabs, but right-clicking on the actual layer should give you all the same tabs (under properties) as any ungrouped layer.

Answer (score 2):

From [Working with group layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/working-with-group-layers.htm):

> A group layer contains other layers. Group layers help organize
>   related kinds of layers in a map and can be used to define advanced
>   drawing options.
>
> ...
>
> A group layer behaves similarly to other layers in the table of
>   contents. ... A group layer's properties override any conflicting
>   properties of its constituent layers.

A group layer is not the same as an ordinary layer.  Although, they have some of the same properties it would not make sense for all properties of all layers within a group layer to be present in its properties.  For example, your group layer might contain point, line and polygon layers, and there might also be a raster layer in that same group layer.